# Directive scope is not populated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
<config-settings model="data"></config-settings>
```

Inside **configSettings** *directive*:

```
directive.scope = {
   model: '='
}
```

The above works fine and **scope.model** has value (data) inside **link** method..However,

```
<config-settings model-test="data"></config-settings>
directive.scope = {
       model: '=modelTest'
    }
```

does not work and **scope.model is undefined**. Why?

Comment: can you provide a plunker?

Comment: Check your **directive.restrict**. It should be **directive.restrict = 'AE';** not '**E**'.